# How to create a responsive popup subscribe modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, responsive

I am trying to create a subscribe popup for the user to click on the subscribe button and to receive notification.

Does anyone know how to make this **popup** become responsive? Need this for my assignment. The button and the popup container are required to responsive. I have tried `width:100%` in @media but the width of the button will become too long. The notification part i have done.

How can I fix this? Please provide some solutions. Thank you

```js
function subOpen() {
    document.getElementById("sub").style.display = "block";
}
function subClose() {
    document.getElementById("sub").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
        .subscribe{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.open-button {
    background-color:cornflowerblue;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 16px 15px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 15%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.sub-title{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}       
.sub-p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1;
}
/* The popup form - hidden by default */
.sub-popup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:100px;
    left:500px;
    border: none;
    border-radius:5px;
    z-index: 9;
}

#sub {
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color:beige;
}
/* Set a style for the subscribe button */
#sub .btn {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:50%;           
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left: 70px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
#sub .cancel {
    background-color: red;
}
#sub .btn:hover, .open-button:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
 <div class= "subscribe">
    <button class="open-button" onclick="subOpen()">SUBSCRIBE</button>
    <div class="sub-popup" id="sub">
        <h4 class="sub-title container">SUBSCRIBE US</h4>
        <p class="sub-p">Click to receive notification to get our updates and special offers now!</p>                               
        <button type="submit" class="btn subscribeBtn">Subscribe</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="subClose()">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.subscribe {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.sub-popup {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 9;
    transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question depends on what you mean by 'make it become responsive', and how you want it to respond.

In general, using units such as vw, vh, and % create sizes that are responsive to your window size.

Media queries can be used if you want styling to change at certain dimensions.

Place this at the end of your CSS, and your popup window will align to the left when your window is 600px or less.

```
@media (max-width: 600px){
.sub-popup{
    left: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The left and bottom using px positioning on the popup form were messing up the responsiveness, first fix that came up to my mind was replacing them with margin 0 auto which basically centers it within it's parent container.
If you're using an absolute unit (px), you need to set media queries to match different screen sizes and change the values accordingly.
I'm not trying to say that using px for sizing is bad, it really depends on what are you trying to achieve so getting familiar with the different units really comes in handy.
There are actually quite a few solutions for this including flexbox, bootstrap, media queries, using relative units.

Hopefully these good reads can help you.
[W3 CSS Units](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)
[What’s The Difference Between PX, EM, REM, %, VW, and VH?](https://elementor.com/help/whats-the-difference-between-px-em-rem-vw-and-vh/)

```js
function subOpen() {
    document.getElementById("sub").style.display = "block";
}
function subClose() {
    document.getElementById("sub").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
        .subscribe{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.open-button {
    background-color:cornflowerblue;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 16px 15px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.8;
    width: 15%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.sub-title{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}       
.sub-p{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1;
}
/* The popup form - hidden by default */
.sub-popup {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto; // replaced left and bottom positioning with margin 0 auto
    border: none;
    border-radius:5px;
    z-index: 9;
}

#sub {
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color:beige;
}
/* Set a style for the subscribe button */
#sub .btn {
    background-color: #04AA6D;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px 20px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width:50%;           
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left: 70px;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
#sub .cancel {
    background-color: red;
}
#sub .btn:hover, .open-button:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
 <div class= "subscribe">
    <button class="open-button" onclick="subOpen()">SUBSCRIBE</button>
    <div class="sub-popup" id="sub">
        <h4 class="sub-title container">SUBSCRIBE US</h4>
        <p class="sub-p">Click to receive notification to get our updates and special offers now!</p>                               
        <button type="submit" class="btn subscribeBtn">Subscribe</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="subClose()">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```